# How to make contents of my page stop making padding with page body

Tags: css

I am building very simple interface, something like Slack. But while doing so, the left navigation makes some padding from the body, however I made padding equals zero and margin.

```css
.app {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.leftNav {
  border: 1px solid black;
  height: 100vh;
  padding: 20px;
  margin: 0;
}
.main {
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="app">
      <div class="leftNav">left navigation</div>
      <div class="main">main content</div>
    </div>
```

Comment: What's your expected output like? :)

Comment: To have the left navigation and main content stick to body with no margin

Comment: `.main {
    padding: 0;
}` and `.leftNav {
    padding: 0;
}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first rule is all you need. It will reset everything to have 0 margin and padding. Therefore, you could easily change them yourself without any problem

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.app {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.leftNav {
  border: 1px solid black;
  height: 100vh;
  padding: 20px;
  margin: 0;
}
.main {
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="app">
      <div class="leftNav">left navigation</div>
      <div class="main">main content</div>
</div>
```

Here's a [working example](https://codepen.io/RaysOfTheSun/pen/pxWqMv) :)

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what you expected but i see these css as default. I mean the space is not app's padding or margin, it's the margin between `<body>` and `<html>` tag.

> body {
>       display: block;
>       margin: 8px; 
>   }